# Exception handler in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception

I have a very simple question; I have a wrong endpoint and when I try the following code, it throws an exception

```
client.post("http://WrongEndPoint", [], function (data, response) {
    console.log("data:", data, "response:", response.statusCode);
})
```

ERROR:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at errnoException (net.js:905:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:896:19)
```

So I try exception handler, but it is still not handeling the exception and I get the same exception:

```
try {
    client.post("http://WrongEndPoint", [], function (data, response) {
        console.log("data:", data, "response:", response.statusCode);
    })
} catch (e) {
    console.log("Error:", e)
}
```

Why can't I still handle the exception?

Comment: The error is thrown asynchrously. You'll need to check the docs of that function you're using on whether and how you can catch it (typically in a callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript **try/catch** statement will not work in this case cause this operation performs asynchronously:

```
client.post("http://WrongEndPoint", [], function (data, response) {
    console.log("data:", data, "response:", response.statusCode);
});
```

To catch it you should use approach like this

```
client.post("http://WrongEndPoint", [], function (data, response) {
    console.log("data:", data, "response:", response.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(err){  console.log(err); });
```

But I'm not sure if it is correct cause I need to know which library do you use.

Comment: it is node-rest-client